# I am new to linux and need help with ubuntu 14.04, Nothing Runs

Tags: 14.04, wine

I used UNetbootin and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with a USB, it took a while and in the end I ended up just deleting my old Windows 7 OS and all the memory. Its installed and set up, and I also have WINE installed too along with PlayonLinux, but from this point on any other software I try to install aside from whats on Ubuntu software center won't run properly.

I'll use WINE and the installer will pop up, it will install the program and everything, but when i click run or click on the icon on my desktop it will pop up and say something like "there has been an error and must abort" on EVERY program I install soldier front, virtualbox, combat arms, etc. I know I'm doing something wrong but can't find anything to help me. Can someone please explain this to me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows programs won't run on linux, only a few special ones or *maybe* with Wine. And Wine is not for every program, see https://www.winehq.org/ or a web search for individual programs.

There are thousand of native linux programs, fonts, etc. Search software center for any, **virtualbox**, fonts, etc. Add universe / multiverse sections of the ubuntu repos, other repos & ppas, or find native linux programs to install, tar.gz packages or source code to build yourself.

### Installing Programs in Ubuntu

<sup>(should apply to Ubuntu-based distros too, [Linux Mint](http://distrowatch.com/mint), [Zorin OS](http://distrowatch.com/zorin), [elementary OS](http://distrowatch.com/elementary), [LXLE](http://distrowatch.com/lxle), [bodhi](http://distrowatch.com/bodhi),  [Chromium OS](http://distrowatch.com/chromixium), etc)</sup>

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware - Ubuntu Help page, links to [Repositories Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories)
- http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/installingsoftware - Shorter, more pics, good site with lots of cats ;-)

### Steam for Linux:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve
- http://store.steampowered.com/about/

### VirtualBox

- https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads  - Direct from virtualbox
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox  -  Older Ubuntu help, maybe outdated but maybe useful

Comment: I don't understand, wine is suppose to help run windows software on linux, but let me be more specific. That's fine, but the real problem is I went to the website you suggested "winehq.org" and found that they suggested oracle virtualbox. This is the exact program I tried running with wine and when installed, I click to open and it says as I stated "there has been an error and need to close" or something of the sort. Can you give me any kind of helpful solution or alternative? As I said, I am new to this OS and software. Thank You

Comment: I think they mean to install the native Linux version of VirtualBox (it's in the Ubuntu repositories - not the windows version with wine), and install windows inside a virtual pc, then run any windows stuff. Maybe slower but should work, even XP ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. They really should have an "Introductory Help" page or something open up when Ubuntu starts for the first time, I tried it about 10yrs ago but didn't have a clue how to install anything either so gave up (temporarily. Mint has a little blurb pop up *I think* and a "help" document or webpage).  I'll add a couple links to basic help installing programs